# Route Table in Ubuntu

Tags: vpn, route

I am new in network and I don't know how to config properly.

I can ping to server

```
ping -I 192.168.42.1 42.112.178.185
```

but I couldn't ping

```
ping 42.112.178.185
```

42.112.178.185 is only allow accept for 192.168.42.0/24.

How could I add route table ? I would like to use

```
ping 42.112.178.185
```

Instead of

```
ping -I 192.168.42.1 42.112.178.185
```

I am trying to call http://42.112.178.185 with curl and need to route from 192.168.42.1.

Comment: btw, curl can take an `--interface` parameter that works much like ping's `-I`

Comment: @A.B, wow. thanks a lot. I was busy for adding route table and now solved with interface. Thanks alot. Can you do as answer instead of comment ? I will mark as correct answer.

Comment: Done. I left the previous solution and added the simpler curl option above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** As wished, here's a solution for the specific problem: have `curl` use the right source ip when connecting, by telling it to bind to it with the `--interface` option before connecting.

From the [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--interface):

> --interface
>
> Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can enter
>   interface name, IP address or host name.

So the problem can be solved by just using this `curl` command to reach 42.112.178.185 with the right IP:

```
curl --interface 192.168.42.1 http://42.112.178.185/
```

Of course you can also specify the interface.

---

I'm still leaving the routing solution below, in case it can help somebody.

---

A route can indeed be added that will tell to use an other source IP than the default IP (the one belonging to the gateway's network) when reaching the target.

note: Because some required informations were not given: the default gateway's IP and the interface to reach it, some additional scripting is required to find out its value. Also because there could be a tunnel which might not have replaced the default route but might have added two "half default routes" 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1, I'll get the route to 42.112.178.185 to have the correct value.

So let's assign the gw IP to `gw`:

```
gw=$(ip -o route get 42.112.178.185 | sed -n 's/^.* via \([^ ][^ ]*\) *.*$/\1/p')
```

Now here's the simple routing command:

```
ip route add 42.112.178.185 src 192.168.42.1 via $gw
```

If for example the gateway was 10.0.8.1, with Ubuntu's supposed tun0's supposed ip 10.0.8.2, before the change, querying the route to 42.112.178.185 would give:

```
# ip route get 42.112.178.185
42.112.178.185 via 10.0.8.1 dev tun0 src 10.0.8.2 
    cache
```

After the change that would become:

```
# ip route get 42.112.178.185
42.112.178.185 via 10.0.8.1 dev tun0 src 192.168.42.1
    cache
```

The `ip route` command can be changed to affect more than this single ip, but what to do depends on the other routes already present.